# Passing argument or having it in class optimisation

Tags: c++, optimization, argument-passing

I'm making a gomoku artificial intelligence and I was wondering myself wich was the best optimized thing to do to have my table available in all my functions. This table is under the form of a `char map[MAPSIZE][MAPSIZE]`. In my algorithm I a lot of read access to this table.

Is it faster to access this map if it's passed as:

- An argument in all my functions.
- A member of my algorithm class.
- A global variable.
- An argument to function but as a pointer.

In a near future I will have to make a lot of copies of this table to implement a search tree.

Thanks for your time,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it makes sense for it to be a class member - make it a class member. This is a design decision that shouldn't be made out of optimization considerations (at least not yet, you can later, after measuring, trade-off design for performance if you think it's worth it).

The alternative is passing it by reference (or pointer, but reference is more C++-ish).

Comment: Exactly the answer I was going to give. Thinking about optimization first of all is premature optimization. Write sensible code - code that makes sense, from an OO point of view.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it faster to access this map if it's passed as: ...

Different methods do incur different runtime costs. However, the difference is almost certainly irrelevant unless you do something grossly inefficient (e.g. unnecessarily copy the entire table in each method).

I suggest you design this with correctness and clarity in mind, and worry about optimizations later.